# File Search for a specific file in entire sdcard in android

Tags: java, android, file-search

I need to search for a specific file in sdcard in android and print the resulted file's absolute path. But when i am running i am getting an error

```
"The application Filecare(process com.example.filecare) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again."
```

I have posted my source code and manifest. Please help me.

*FileSearch.java*

```
package com.example.filecare;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class FileSearch extends Activity {

    EditText fnn;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_file_search);
        fnn=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    }
    public void Searchstart(View v)
    {
        searchfn();
    }
    @SuppressLint("SdCardPath")
    public void searchfn()
    {
        File root = new File("/sdcard/");
        String results,fileName = fnn.getText().toString();
           // result=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.result);        
        try {
            boolean recursive = true;

            Collection files = FileUtils.listFiles(root, null, recursive);

            for (Iterator iterator = files.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                File file = (File) iterator.next();
                if (file.getName().equals(fileName))
                    System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
                    //file.delete();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File Exists", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.file_search, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

*AndroidManifest.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.filecare"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.filecare.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.filecare.Home"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.filecare.Login"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.filecare.Home"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.filecare.Home" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.filecare.Register"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_register"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.filecare.Home" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.filecare.Home" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.filecare.FileOperations"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_file_operations"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.filecare.Login" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.filecare.Login" />
        </activity>        
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.filecare.FileSearch"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_file_search" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Now I have posted my new logcat please help me with this problem..
    *Log*

```
01-28 16:07:02.153: D/dalvikvm(269): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 735 objects / 54888 bytes in 77ms
01-28 16:07:06.273: D/dalvikvm(269): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 396 objects / 19976 bytes in 47ms
01-28 16:07:10.613: W/KeyCharacterMap(269): No keyboard for id 0
01-28 16:07:10.623: W/KeyCharacterMap(269): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
01-28 16:07:15.494: I/dalvikvm(269): Could not find method com.example.filecare.FileOperations.getActionBar, referenced from method com.example.filecare.FileOperations.setupActionBar
01-28 16:07:15.494: W/dalvikvm(269): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 5062: Lcom/example/filecare/FileOperations;.getActionBar ()Landroid/app/ActionBar;
01-28 16:07:15.494: D/dalvikvm(269): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
01-28 16:07:15.494: D/dalvikvm(269): VFY: dead code 0x0009-000d in Lcom/example/filecare/FileOperations;.setupActionBar ()V
01-28 16:07:17.904: I/dalvikvm(269): Could not find method org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.listFiles, referenced from method com.example.filecare.FileSearch.searchfn
01-28 16:07:17.924: W/dalvikvm(269): VFY: unable to resolve static method 5360: Lorg/apache/commons/io/FileUtils;.listFiles (Ljava/io/File;[Ljava/lang/String;Z)Ljava/util/Collection;
01-28 16:07:17.924: D/dalvikvm(269): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0013
01-28 16:07:17.934: D/dalvikvm(269): VFY: dead code 0x0016-0020 in Lcom/example/filecare/FileSearch;.searchfn ()V
01-28 16:07:17.934: D/dalvikvm(269): VFY: dead code 0x0022-0049 in Lcom/example/filecare/FileSearch;.searchfn ()V
01-28 16:07:22.343: D/AndroidRuntime(269): Shutting down VM
01-28 16:07:22.343: W/dalvikvm(269): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
01-28 16:07:22.353: E/AndroidRuntime(269): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-28 16:07:22.353: E/AndroidRuntime(269): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
01-28 16:07:22.353: E/AndroidRuntime(269):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2072)
01-28 16:07:22.353: E/AndroidRuntime(269):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
01-28 16:07:22.353: E/AndroidRuntime(269):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
01-28 16:07:22.353: E/AndroidRuntime(269):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-28 16:07:22.353: E/AndroidRuntime(269):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-28 16:07:22.353: E/AndroidRuntime(269):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-28 16:07:22.353: E/AndroidRuntime(269):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-28 16:07:22.353: E/AndroidRuntime(269):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-28 16:07:22.353: E/AndroidRuntime(269):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-28 16:07:22.353: E/AndroidRuntime(269):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-28 16:07:22.353: E/AndroidRuntime(269):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-28 16:07:22.353: E/AndroidRuntime(269):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-28 16:07:22.353: E/AndroidRuntime(269): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-28 16:07:22.353: E/AndroidRuntime(269):  at com.example.filecare.FileSearch.Searchstart(FileSearch.java:28)
01-28 16:07:22.353: E/AndroidRuntime(269):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-28 16:07:22.353: E/AndroidRuntime(269):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-28 16:07:22.353: E/AndroidRuntime(269):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2067)
01-28 16:07:22.353: E/AndroidRuntime(269):  ... 11 more
01-28 16:07:22.353: E/AndroidRuntime(269): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils
01-28 16:07:22.353: E/AndroidRuntime(269):  at com.example.filecare.FileSearch.searchfn(FileSearch.java:39)
01-28 16:07:22.353: E/AndroidRuntime(269):  ... 15 more
01-28 16:07:30.174: I/Process(269): Sending signal. PID: 269 SIG: 9
```

I posted the layout xml file
    *activity_file_search.xml*

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".FileSearch" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="42dp"
        android:onClick="Searchstart"
        android:text="Search" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="38dp"
        android:ems="10" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post a log, and stop *assuming* what the mount point of the sdcard is.

Comment: you have set an onClick listener for a `button1` in the xml where that button is defined, right? If so please post that xml

Comment: I have posted the Logcat and xml file. Help me with the problem

Comment: You have define your method as public void Searchstart(View v){}

Comment: I have changed the public void Searchstart() to Searchstart(View v), but still the same error comes... i have posted the new Logcat. Please solve the problem

Comment: from the stacktrace, it would seem you are using `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils` somewhere, which I dont think is available in all android devices

Answer (score 0):

before you use code need to get permission to read and write on the storage.

Insert code before the application tag on manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

i do not know java code sorry.